# Having Eclipse PyDev auto-complete after two letters instead of three

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

By default, Eclipse PyDev suggests some variable and function name auto-completions after the user types 3 letters. How to configure Eclipse PyDev to reduce this number to one or two?

[image]

Here is my auto-completion settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure it at preferences > pydev > editor > code completion (ctx insensitive and common tokens).

Comment: Thanks, I do have it set to `1`, but I still have the issue shown in the animated gif in the question.

Comment: Same here. Funny detail: if I start writing the variable in upper case, I get the completion from the first character on. If I use the correct case, I have to type three characters before getting the completion. Ctrl-Space works after the first character.